# I am reversing those elements, which are divisible by 2. Unable to print "T" in the input "Three"

Tags: javascript

I am reversing those elements, which are divisible by  2 (length of element). Unable to print "T" in the input "Three".

Using Map method

```js
let name = "One Two Three Four";
let newMap = name.split(" ").map(el=>{if(el.length%2!==0){
    el = el.split("").map(el1=>el[el.length-el.indexOf(el1)-1])
}else{
    el = el.split("").map(el1=>el[el.indexOf(el1)])
}
return el;
})
console.log(newMap);
```

Unable to print "T" in the element "Three" Using map method only [ 'e', 'e', 'r', 'h', 'h' ]

Comment: You'll want to add a language tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `el.indexOf(el1)` you can just use the index that `Array#map` already gives you as the second argument to your callback. Your example fails because `indexOf` looks for the *first* occurence of the string and for "Three" this yields indicies [0, 1, 2, 3, 3] - therefor your last call overrides the letter with "e".

```js
let name = "One Two Three Four";
let newMap = name.split(" ").map((el) => {
  if (el.length % 2 !== 0) {
    //                       vvv this gives you the current index
    el = el.split("").map((_, i) => el[el.length - i - 1]);
  } else {
    // also, you don't actually need this line since it just copies the string
    // and strings are immutable
    el = el.split("").map((_, i) => el[i]);
  }
  return el;
});
```

Also, see the documentation for Array#map here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map